# netbeans error on running android projects

Tags: android, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I have installed java 8 and netbeans 8.2. I added android support on netbeans using https://bitbucket.org/nbandroid/nbandroid/wiki/Installation . I pointed sdk location created by android studio. I have created AVD. I created my first android project on netbeans. But when I am running or cleaning and building that app I am getting error message "build.xml:1: Premature end of file."
What could be the cause of this problem. I am able to create and run android apps on android studio successfully so I think there is no problem with android sdk. I tried netbeans 8.1 also but same problem is happenning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nbandroid doesnt work with NetBeans 8.2, But i found a fork call nbandroid2, [here](https://github.com/NBANDROIDTEAM/NBANDROID-V2)
[Here](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Plugin-Installation-Error-NBAndroid-td5751917.html) is the comment from developers he says "I stopped maintaining NBAdroid plugin a while ago. Basically because I am no longer motivated to do so."